# Histogram from streets coordinates in Netlogo

Tags: gis, netlogo, shapefile

I have loaded a GIS shapefile in Netlogo with coordinates of street ends. 
Doing

```
set nodes-dataset gis:load-dataset "nodes.shp"
show gis:feature-list-of nodes-dataset gives me the list of gis features


[{{gis:VectorFeature ["HIGHWAY":""]["LON":"3.7282846"]["OSMID":"145809"]["LAT":"51.0559224"]}} {{gis:VectorFeature ["HIGHWAY":""]["LON":"3.717492"]["OSMID":"82775029"]["LAT":"51.0563512"]}} {{gis:VectorFeature ["HIGHWAY":""]["LON":"3.7173761"]["OSMID":"82775030"]["LAT":"51.0567027"]}} {{gis:VectorFeature ["HIGHWAY":""]["LON":"3.7182838"]["OSMID":"82775032"]["LAT":"51.0577545"]}} {{gis:VectorFeature ["HIGHWAY":""]["LON":"3.7187206"]["OSMI .....
```

which contains LAT and LON of each node.

Similarly, I also have loaded into Netlogo the shapefile of the streets/roads that joins these nodes.

Is there a way to compute street distance between those nodes?.

The aim is to get a list of distances and plot them with an histogram.

Thank you for your help

Comment: The other shapefile, the one with the edges, has a property "LENGTH" of the connected link (street) between pairs. To get the lengths of the streets I just would need to collect those values in a list. Does the Netlogo gis extensión any form to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the "LENGTH" between each pair of nodes as a property of the VectorFeatures of my shapefile.
To extract that numbers I run

```
let dim-street []
foreach gis:feature-list-of edges-dataset [ [?1] ->
    set dim-street lput ( read-from-string gis:property-value ?1 "LENGTH" ) dim-street
  ]
```